# Detect when window is closed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, window, nswindowcontroller

One of my classes allocates a custom `NSWindowController`, how can my class know when the window gets closed?

```
CustomNSWindowController *wc = [[CustomNSWindowController alloc] init];
[wc showWindow:self];
//how to detect when window is closed?
```

What I'm trying to do is have the original class (the one that allocates the custom window controller) know when the window is closed so that I can set wc = nil when the window is no longer needed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `NSWindowController` class is set as the window's delegate, you can simply respond to the `-windowWillClose:` method.

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Otherwise, since this is also a notification, you can register to receive the notification from any class.

```
- (void)myWindowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    /* ... */
}

...
CustomNSWindowController *wc = ...;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(myWindowWillClose:)
    name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification
    object:[wc window]];
[wc showWindow:self];
```

See [NSWindow Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSWindowDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I don't have the option of `[wc setDelegate:self]` the method does not exist. What I'm trying to do is have the original class (the one that allocates the custom window controller) know when the window is closed so that I can set `wc = nil` when the window is no longer needed :)

Comment: "Otherwise, since this is also a notification, you can register to receive the notification from any class."

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm new to app development and the code really helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you could either send a notification, or make your parent class the delegate of the CustomNSWindowController.

[edit] - Dietrich is right - I forgot about the NSWindow delegate protocol.  You could set the parent class as the delegate of the window of the windowController

Answer (score 0):

use delegate **- (BOOL)isWindowLoaded** to check if it closed or not :
to the documentation of this delegate 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

also if you like the to take a look inside the close window

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html